# Maximum principle for nonlocal equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, fractional-calculus, maximum-principle

I was reading this paper:

> Luis Silvestre - On the differentiability of the solution to the
> Hamilton-Jacobi equation with critical fractional diffusion (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.5147.pdf)

In Lemma 3.3, the author proved a comparison principle for (bounded solution) to the nonlocal equation of the following form ($M^+$ is the maximal operator)

$$
u_t - A|\nabla u| - M^+u \leq 0.
$$

To show this, the author constructed a smooth supersolution
$$
\varphi_t - A|\nabla \varphi | - M^+\varphi > 0.
$$

by

- Assume $M > \sup_{x,t} u(x,t)$ and there is some $(x_0,t_0)$ with $t_0>0$ such that $u(x_0,t_0) > \sup_x u(x_0,0)$.
- Let $H = M - u(x_0,t_0)$ and $\epsilon \ll (u(x_0,t_0) - \sup_x u(x,0))/(1+A)$
- Then
  $$
  \varphi(x,t) = M - h \left(\frac{1}{1+|\lambda(x-x_0)|^2}\right) + (1+A)h\epsilon t
  $$
  for $\lambda$ small. The author then claims that there exists $h>0$ so that $u-\varphi$ has a maximum at $(x_1,t_1)$ with $t_1>0$. However, his claim on
  $$ \varphi(x,0) > u(x,0)$$
  for all $h>0$ appears to be not correct, as it can only be true for small $h$.

My question is how can we make sure the maximum happens at a positive time to finish this argument?